# Purchase a home as primary residence but rent it until current lease is up

Tags: mortgage, rental-property, primary-residence

If I purchase a home as a primary residence, how can I rent it out until my current apartment lease is up (about 1 year)?

My intent is to use it as a primary residence, just not within the 60 days that owner occupancy affidavits typically require.

Is there flexibility on this with lenders?

Comment: Why don't you ask the lenders?

Comment: Why are you planning to buy the house so far in advance of occupancy ?

Comment: What country are you, as different countries may also bring up different tax issues regarding your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there isn't flexibility. They have a different loan products for properties that aren't going to be used a a personal residence. They may make a different loan for rental properties, and one for vacation properties.

These other products will have different interest rates and different down payment requirements.

Depending on the neighborhood you may run into issues if you buy and immediately rent. Generally this is due to a high number of rentals already in the condo association. Some government loan programs can't be used in these situations.

You may have to wait before buying.